# Eclipse ctrl+click refers to wrong line

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I have been facing this problem that when I ctrl+click on a method name to go inside that method, it points me somewhere else. Closing the editor and reopening doesn't fix the issue, I have to restart the eclipse which is so frustrating. 
Does anyone know why it's happening so and the fix to it?

eclipse version: 4.5.0

os: ubuntun 14.04

Comment: Looks like it caches old version of source code where desired method is located

Comment: Where is this somewhere else? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

Using eclipse Hyperlinking you can open following:

[image]

So if it is opening declaration Ex: interface declaration, then try implementation option.

See following for more details:

- [Easy navigation in Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-galnav/)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I face this issue but will get fixed if eclipse is relaunched.
Anyway, try this.

Clean-build the workspace:

1. Save all your files in the workspace.
2. Project -> clean -> 'Clean selected projects below'
3. Check your workspace if unchecked
4. Check 'Start a build immediately' if
       unchecked and click 'ok'

Now try 'ctrl + click' or F3 in eclipse to goto method definition.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your Eclipse version : Goto Project Explorer > Your Source Directory > Right Click > Index > Rebuild.